# Массив структур: сортировка.

Tags: c

Есть массив структур: <фамилия> <имя> <результат>. Нужно отсортировать его в алфавитном порядке(по первой букве фамилии):

пишу:

```
for (i = st - 1; i >= 0;i-- ){
    mm = 0;
    for (j = 0 ; j <= i ; j++){
        if (dig1[j].fam[0] > dig1[i].fam[0]){
            mm = j;
            tmp = dig1[i];
            dig1[i] = dig1[mm];
            dig1[mm] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

чет не работает.Помогите найти ошибку.Спасибо.

Вся задача:
7) В некотором вузе абитуриенты проходят предварительное тестирование, по результатам которого могут быть допущены к сдаче вступительных экзаменов в первом потоке. Тестирование проводится по двум предметам, по каждому предмету абитуриент может набрать от 0 до 100 баллов. При этом к сдаче экзаменов в первом потоке допускаются абитуриенты, набравшие по результатам тестирования не менее 30 баллов по каждому из двух предметов. На вход программы подаются сведения о результатах предварительного тестирования. Известно, что общее количество участников тестирования не превосходит 500. 
В первой строке вводится количество абитуриентов, принимавших участие в тестировании, N. Далее следуют N строк, имеющих следующий формат:

<Фамилия> <Имя> <Баллы>

Здесь <Фамилия> – строка, состоящая не более чем из 20 символов; <Имя> – строка, состоящая не более чем из 15 символов; <Баллы> – строка, содержащая два целых числа, разделенных пробелом, соответствующих баллам, полученным на тестировании по каждому из двух предметов. При этом <Фамилия> и <Имя>, <Имя> и <Баллы> разделены одним пробелом. Примеры входных строк:

Ветров Роман 68 59

Анисимова Екатерина 64 88

Напишите программу, которая будет выводить на экран фамилии и имена абитуриентов, потерпевших неудачу, то есть не допущенных к сдаче экзаменов в первом потоке. При этом фамилии должны выводиться в алфавитном порядке.

Я пишу:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

main(){
    struct Rezultat {
        char fam[20];
        char name[15];
        int rez;    
    } Rez;
    int rez1;
    int rez2;
    struct Rezultat dig[100];
    struct Rezultat dig1[100];
    struct Rezultat tmp;
    int i,j,n,mm,st;

    printf("Введите число участников: \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Введите имена и результаты участников: \n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
        scanf("%s %s %d %d",Rez.fam,Rez.name,&rez1,&rez2);
        Rez.rez = rez1 + rez2;
        dig[i] = Rez;
    }
    /*заполняем второй массив неудачниками*/
    st = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
        if(dig[i].rez  < 60){
            dig1[st] = dig[i];
            st++;
        }
    }
    if( st == 0){
        printf("Все справились с заданием");
    }
    /*Сортируем массив неудачников в алфавитном порядке*/
    for (i = st - 1; i >= 0;i-- ){
        mm = 0;
        for (j = 0 ; j <= i ; j++){
            if (dig1[j].fam[0] > dig1[i].fam[0]){
                mm = j;
                tmp = dig1[i];
                dig1[i] = dig1[mm];
                dig1[mm] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n") ;
    for (i = st - 1; i >= 0; i++ ){
        printf ("%s %s\n",dig1[i].fam,dig1[i].name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

При тесте выводит ввожу три фамилии ,две из которых "неудачники". на вывод выходит только одна.Может вывод неправильный,но там вроде нормально написано.

Работает,всем спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Внимательно смотрим на эту строчку и пытаемся осознать всю эпичность опечатки:

```
for (j = 0 ; j <= j ; j++)
```

**UPD**

Ещё ошибка в цикле поиска "неудачников". Он должен выглядеть так:

```
st = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
    if(dig[i].rez  < 60){
        dig1[st] = dig[i];
        st++;
    }
}
```

Comment: ааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа

Comment: исправил,не работает

Comment: Если сортировать нужно только по первой букве фамилии, то в приведённом куске кода ошибок нет. Попробуйте привести больше кода и входные данные, на которых оно не работает.

Comment: Ещё не ясен смысл переменной mm - она же вроде не нужна, достаточно использовать вместо неё j?

Comment: Не нужна. Впрочем, она и не мешает.

Comment: У меня заготовка из Крупника ещё была.Я копирнул,вот откуда mm